# Problems with errors when using aot Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ivy

I had a project with Angular 8 and updated it to Angular 9. But when I try to use Ivy, it gives me weird errors. For example, it sticks to Angular material tags if all its modules are imported correctly. Even when I'm not using aot ( set `aot = false` in `angular.json` ), the project runs quite well.

error :

```
node_modules/ng2-file-upload/file-upload/file-upload.module.d.ts:1:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of FormTryModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (ng2-file-upload) which declares FileUploadModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

1 export declare class FileUploadModule {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@agm/core/core.module.d.ts:28:79 - error NG6005: AgmCoreModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type. If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.

28     static forRoot(lazyMapsAPILoaderConfig?: LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral): ModuleWithProviders;
                                                                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/app/core/options/options.component.html:14:95 - error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type 'OptionsComponent'.

14       <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="options.collapsed" (change)="sendOptions()" [labelPosition]="end">Collapsed Sidebar</mat-checkbox>
                                                                                                 ~~~

  src/app/core/options/options.component.ts:7:18
    7     templateUrl: 'options.component.html'
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component OptionsComponent.
src/app/core/options/options.component.html:17:93 - error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type 'OptionsComponent'.

17       <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="options.compact" (change)="sendOptions()" [labelPosition]="end">Compact Sidebar</mat-checkbox>
                                                                                               ~~~

  src/app/core/options/options.component.ts:7:18
    7     templateUrl: 'options.component.html'
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component OptionsComponent.
src/app/core/options/options.component.html:20:91 - error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type 'OptionsComponent'.

20       <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="options.boxed" (change)="sendOptions()" [labelPosition]="end">Boxed Layout</mat-checkbox>
                                                                                             ~~~

  src/app/core/options/options.component.ts:7:18
    7     templateUrl: 'options.component.html'
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component OptionsComponent.
src/app/core/options/options.component.html:23:90 - error TS2339: Property 'end' does not exist on type 'OptionsComponent'.

23       <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="options.dark" (change)="sendOptions()" [labelPosition]="end">Dark Mode</mat-checkbox>
                                                                                            ~~~

  src/app/core/options/options.component.ts:7:18
    7     templateUrl: 'options.component.html'
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component OptionsComponent.
src/app/core/footer/footer.component.html:11:7 - error TS2339: Property 'userName' does not exist on type 'FooterComponent'.

11       {{userName}}
         ~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/footer/footer.component.ts:11:18
    11     templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FooterComponent.
src/app/core/footer/footer.component.html:16:7 - error TS2339: Property 'role' does not exist on type 'FooterComponent'.

16       {{role}}
         ~~~~

  src/app/core/footer/footer.component.ts:11:18
    11     templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component FooterComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:1:53 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

1 <div class="app mat-typography" [dir]="options.dir" [ngClass]="{'app-dark': options.dark, 'boxed': options.boxed, 'collapsed-sidebar': options.collapsed, 'compact-sidebar': options.compact, 'side-panel-opened': sidePanelOpened, 'side-panel-closed': !sidePanelOpened }">
                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:2:3 - error NG8001: 'ngx-loading-bar' is not a known element:
1. If 'ngx-loading-bar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ngx-loading-bar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2   <ngx-loading-bar color="#009688"></ngx-loading-bar>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:3:3 - error NG8001: 'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3   <app-header (toggleSidenav)="sidemenu.toggle()" (toggleNotificationSidenav)="notifications.toggle()"></app-header>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:5:3 - error NG8001: 'mat-sidenav-container' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav-container' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

5   <mat-sidenav-container class="app-inner">
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:6:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-sidenav' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

6     <mat-sidenav #sidemenu class="sidebar-panel admin" id="sidebar-panel" [mode]="isOver() ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!isOver()"
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
7       (openedStart)="sidePanelOpened = true" (closedStart)="sidePanelOpened = false" (mouseover)="menuMouseOver()"
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
8       (mouseout)="menuMouseOut()" [perfectScrollbar]="config" [disabled]="mediaMatcher.matches">
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:6:75 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'mode' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-sidenav'.
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component and it has 'mode' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

6     <mat-sidenav #sidemenu class="sidebar-panel admin" id="sidebar-panel" [mode]="isOver() ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!isOver()"
                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:6:111 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'opened' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-sidenav'.
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component and it has 'opened' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

6     <mat-sidenav #sidemenu class="sidebar-panel admin" id="sidebar-panel" [mode]="isOver() ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="!isOver()"
                                                                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:8:35 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'perfectScrollbar' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-sidenav'.
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component and it has 'perfectScrollbar' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

8       (mouseout)="menuMouseOut()" [perfectScrollbar]="config" [disabled]="mediaMatcher.matches">
                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:8:63 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-sidenav'.
1. If 'mat-sidenav' is an Angular component and it has 'disabled' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

8       (mouseout)="menuMouseOut()" [perfectScrollbar]="config" [disabled]="mediaMatcher.matches">
                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:9:7 - error NG8001: 'app-sidebar' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

9       <app-sidebar (click)="updatePS()"></app-sidebar>
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:15:7 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

15       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:21:3 - error NG8001: 'app-options' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-options' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-options' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

21   <app-options (messageEvent)="receiveOptions($event)"></app-options>
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16
    25   templateUrl: './admin-layout.component.html',
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AdminLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.html:28:1 - error NG8001: 'app-footer' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

28 <app-footer></app-footer>
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/admin-layout/admin-layout.component.ts:25:16

  src/app/core/auth-layout/auth-layout.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './auth-layout.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AuthLayoutComponent.
src/app/core/auth-layout/auth-layout.component.html:2:3 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

2   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/auth-layout/auth-layout.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './auth-layout.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:3:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3     <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:9:31 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngStyle.xs' since it isn't a known property of 'form'.

9     <form class="search-form" [ngStyle.xs]="{display: 'none'}">
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:10:7 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

10       <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
         ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:15:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

15     <mat-icon>fullscreen</mat-icon>
       ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:18:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

18     <mat-icon>notifications</mat-icon>
       ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:21:11 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'matMenuTriggerFor' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

21   <button [matMenuTriggerFor]="user" mat-icon-button class="ml-xs">
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:22:5 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

22     <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
       ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:24:3 - error NG8001: 'mat-menu' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

24   <mat-menu #user="matMenu" x-position="before">
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:26:7 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

26       <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
         ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:30:7 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

34       <mat-icon>notifications_off</mat-icon>
         ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/header/header.component.html:38:7 - error NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

38       <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
         ~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/header/header.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './header.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HeaderComponent.
src/app/core/sidebar/sidebar.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'app-menu' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <app-menu></app-menu>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/sidebar/sidebar.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component SidebarComponent.
src/app/core/notification/notification.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-tab-group' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-tab-group' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab-group' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

1 <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="1" mat-stretch-tabs>
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/notification/notification.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './notification.component.html'
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component NotificationComponent.
src/app/core/notification/notification.component.html:1:16 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'selectedIndex' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tab-group'.
1. If 'mat-tab-group' is an Angular component and it has 'selectedIndex' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-tab-group' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

1 <mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="1" mat-stretch-tabs>
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/core/notification/notification.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './notification.component.html'
```

pakcage.json:

```
{
  "name": "primer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.7",
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.31",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "9.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.9",
    "@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet": "7.0.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.2",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "3.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^16.1.1",
    "@types/dragula": "^2.1.35",
    "angular-calendar": "0.28.15",
    "angular-highcharts": "^9.0.11",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "d3": "5.7.0",
    "date-fns": "1.29.0",
    "dragula": "3.7.2",
    "highcharts": "^7.2.1",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jalali-moment": "^3.3.4",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "leaflet": "1.3.4",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "moment-hijri": "^2.1.2",
    "moment-jalaali": "^0.8.3",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "2.1.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.3.0",
    "ng2-loading-spinner": "^1.3.0",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.9.20",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.4.4",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^1.5.1",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "9.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "12.0.1",
    "quill": "1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "6.5.5",
    "screenfull": "3.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "uuid": "^8.1.0",
    "videogular2": "7.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.1.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.1.9",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

thanks for your help . If you need anything, tell me in the comments so I can add it.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain a simple error that i have understand in this stack trace.

```
node_modules/@agm/core/core.module.d.ts:28:79 - error NG6005: AgmCoreModule.forRoot returns a ModuleWithProviders type without a generic type argument. Please add a generic type argument to the ModuleWithProviders type. If this occurrence is in library code you don't control, please contact the library authors.

28     static forRoot(lazyMapsAPILoaderConfig?: LazyMapsAPILoaderConfigLiteral): ModuleWithProviders;
```

According to Angular official documentation (starting from Angular 9) ModuleWithProviders is deprecated. Code needs to be migrated.

> [Angular ModuleWithProviders Migration](https://angular.io/guide/migration-module-with-providers)

As stated by Angular, libraries that are not yet migrated can be used and will be automaticaly migrated by Angular compatibility compiler (ngcc).

According to [Angular compatability compiler](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

you can add in your package.json the following:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  }
}
```

Then you can remove this module by

```
npm uninstall @agm/core
```

And then you can try to add this module again but passing it from ngcc which will do the ModuleWithProviders migration by executing

```
ng add @agm/core
```

Hopefully doing that will remove this specific error. Other errors may relate to that and you can dig deeper.